# JavaFX - Update a text field through observer pattern

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, textfield, observer-pattern

I am trying to update a text field through observer pattern. The update function in the observer (FXML controller) is called after clicking on a listItem in another controller class. And that works fine. The only problem is that my textfield won't update.

Here is my update function in the observer.

```
@Override
public void update(Observable o, final Object arg) {
    System.out.println("test");         // works
    firstNameTextField.setText("test"); // doesn't work (text field is still empty)
    System.out.println(firstNameTextField.getText()); //works and shows me the word "test" on my console
}
```

The funny thing is, if I print the text from the text field on my console it's printing the word "test" on the console. It seems like the text field value is updated but it doesn't show up on the ui.

---

**EDIT:**
This is my MainController

```
public class MainController extends Observable implements Initializable {

    private ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList("item1", "item2");
    private List<UserProfile> userProfiles = new ArrayList<UserProfile>();
    private String[] tabTitles = { "Profile"};

    @FXML
    private TabPane tabPane;

    @FXML
    ListView<String> listView;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

        for (String tabTitle : tabTitles) {
        Tab tab = new Tab(tabTitle);
        tab.setClosable(false);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
    }

    tabPane.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();

    for (Tab tab : tabPane.getTabs()) {
        try {
            String newStringValue = tab.getText();

            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("profile.fxml"));
            tab.setContent(root);


        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();

        Object p = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("profile.fxml").openStream());
        if (fxmlLoader.getController() instanceof ProfileController) {
            ProfileController profileController = (ProfileController) fxmlLoader.getController();
            this.addObserver(profileController);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
     tabPane.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();

    listView.setItems(items);
    listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers();
        }

    });

}
}
```

ProfileController

```
public class ProfileController implements Initializable, Observer {

    @FXML
    TextField firstNameTextField;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, final Object arg) {
        System.out.println("test");         // works
        firstNameTextField.setText("test"); // doesn't work (text field is still empty)
        System.out.println(firstNameTextField.getText()); //works and shows me the word "test" on my console
    }
}
```

---

Can anybody help me out with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show how you are passing the reference to one controller to the other controller?

Comment: Yeah, that really doesn't help. Instead of posting unrelated code snippets, you should probably create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows just enough to fully recreate the problem. It looks like you have a reference to a different instance of the controller class to the one that is actually connected to the UI, but there's no way to tell that from the code you have posted. (E.g., what are you doing with `p` that you get from the loader?)

Comment: @James_D sry for that. I've added a MCVE

Comment: @James_D I do nothing with p. I don't need it

Comment: Uh, the controller you are using is the controller for `p`, which contains the `TextField` you are manipulating. So if you do nothing with `p`, how would you ever expect to see the text field change?

Comment: But if I add p as an observer instead of fxmlLoader.getController() the update function is never called

Comment: You're missing the point. You have the wrong controller instance. Somewhere (you haven't shown your code, again, it helps if you could write an MCVE) you load profile.fxml *and display the content*. You need to get *that* controller instance and arrange for its `update(...)` method to be called, not just some other arbitrary instance.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute

```
    Object p = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("profile.fxml").openStream());
    if (fxmlLoader.getController() instanceof ProfileController) {
        ProfileController profileController = (ProfileController) fxmlLoader.getController();
        this.addObserver(profileController);
    }
```

you load the structure represented by profile.fxml, and place that hierarchy (including `firstNameTextField`) in the object you called `p`. When you invoke `update(...)` on `profileController`, it changes the text in the text field that is part of the hierarchy of `p`. However, you never do anything with `p`: you don't display it in your UI. So when you change the text of the text field, the changes are of course invisible (because you are changing a text field that isn't displayed).

Presumably, since you said you have the text field displayed, somewhere in the code you couldn't be bothered to include you are loading `profile.fxml` *and displaying the content in the UI*. You need to get the reference to *that* controller, and register it as an observer. Registering an arbitrary instance of the same class will not have the desired effect.